# get some Error with creating and inserting object of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am new in iPhone and now I am struggling to create and inserting object.
I explain first

Here I have one tableview with some cell value which is getting from my array whose  name is `appDelegate.array1` 
now I can change some value in table view cell and now after that I want to insert this new cell value in same array appDelegate.array1.  So how can I do this. 
I tried to do it like this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{           
    [appDelegate.array1 addObject:indexPath];

    [tableView reloadData];     
}
```

it is correct or not if yes then why my application will terminate and if not then please give me correct method to add object in array

Comment: Post more of your code and log (where it did crash) ...

Answer (score 0):

How are you declear your array?

you need to make it a `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *array1;
```

Comment: ya its a mutableArray array1 that i declare and i share it with appdelegate my problem is i change some cell value in tableveiw which is coming from my array and now i just want to resave this new cell value in my old array please help

Comment: Can your paste your crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Note this points.

1) Check if your array is Mutable array...Then only you can add new items to array at run time
2) What is indexPath in your code, which is bit confusing..

3) To add object you use these (or more)functions

```
[yourArray addObject:your_object];
```

Or to insert into the array you can use

```
[yourArray insertObject:your_object atIndex:your_index];
```

Hope this help

Comment: ya my array is mutable array please tell me how can i add only new item to an array

Answer (score 0):

Your method is right but there can be number of problems in ur logic.

Like you add `indexPath`. (what is in `indexPath`?) is it `nil` or something like that.
your `appDelegate` object correctly initialized or not.

There is certainly a problem in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading entire table view for adding just one item, Just add the element to the array and update the table view....

```
    -(void) addObject : (id) inObject
    {
        if(inObject)
        {
        [appDelegate.array1 addObject:inObject];
        [mTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
```